# When running a smart contract, what exactly happens on the blockchain?

Tags: solidity, transactions, blockchain, contract-deployment

When somebody runs a smart contract, what part goes into the blockchain?

The whole contract (in Solidity), only the transaction or the complete execution (contract and input data)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contract, transaction, and final state of executing the contract, is on the blockchain.  Intermediate execution results are not stored on the blockchain.

New values in the storage of contracts, and events that are triggered, are written to the blockchain.  Since contracts can create other contracts, the code of such contracts are also added.